# Function Pointer parameter from any class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Hey is it somehow possible to take a function pointer as parameter from any other class?

I would like to have class with a map, which stores function pointers from another class.

```
void MyClass::MyMethod((AnyClass::*func)())
{
  //add to container
}
```

Right now I'm storing the function pointers in the same class. But MyMethod should have it's own class taking function pointers from any class (but one instance with the Map will only take function pointers from the same class like obj1 only has funcptrs from class1, obj2 only contains funcptrs from class2 etc),

```
typedef void (MyClass::*func_ptr(float delta);

void MyClass::MyMethod(const std::string& id, func_ptr func)
{
    std::pair<std::string,func_ptr> state_pair (id,func);
    state_map_.insert(state_pair);
}
```

I've already tried it with templates, but I think I do not use them correctly.
can anyone help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your edit. Are you saying that you want a different map object for each class you are storing member function pointers of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use templates:

```
template <typename Ret, class T, typename... Args>
void MyClass::MyMethod(Ret (T::*func) (Args...))
{  }
```

How you store them in a container depends on if you'll only be adding functions with the same signature or not. You could template `MyClass` like that and create a container for storing member functions with one signature. Otherwise, you could create a wrapper functor.

**Edit:**

If I understand you correctly, you want a templated `MyClass` which stores a map from strings to member functions and a member function `MyMethod` which stores into that map? Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    std::map<std::string, void(T::*)(float)> m_map;

    void MyMethod(const std::string &id, void (T::*func) (float))
    {
        m_map[id] = func;
    }
};
```

Comment: yeah the signature stays the same

Comment: what if i have a second method inside this template which should execute all the functions stored as function pointer in the map?
without templates i used this:
 `(this->*my_map_.at(mystring))(floatvalue);`

Comment: ok i think i found my solution, i'll just hand over the callers intance per parameter. now its working :)